# how to pass parameter into setup_method for pytest

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, pytest-django

I need to write some testcase to test user's permission. in each testcase, UserA has different permission and do the checking. I would like to use admin role to provide userA different permission in setup_method. How I can pass parameter into setup_method so before each testcase start, I can have different testcase? I have something like following but not sure how to pass parameter into setup_method.

```
class TestPermission():

    @classmethod
    class setup_method(self, permission):
        login as amdin
        provide permission to userA
        logout
        login as userA

    @classmethod
    class teardown_method(self):
        logout as userA

    @fixure(permission1)
    class test_permissionA(self):
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission1"]') is True
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission2"]') is False
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission3"]') is False

    @fixure(permission2)
    class test_permissionB(self):
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission1"]') is False
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission2"]') is True
        assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission3"]') is False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parametrized fixtures here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize

So the final code will look something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", params=[{'permission': 'permission1', 'expected_result': {'perm1': True, 'perm2': False, 'perm3': False}}, {'permission': 'permission2', 'expected_result': {'perm1': False, 'perm2': True, 'perm3': False}}])
def test_cases(request):
  admin_user.set_permission_to_userA(request.param.get('permission'))
  return request.param

def test_userA_permissions(test_cases):
  login_with_userA()
  assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission1"]') is test_cases.get('expected_result').get('perm1')
  assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission2"]') is test_cases.get('expected_result').get('perm2')
  assert drive.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="permission3"]') is test_cases.get('expected_result').get('perm3')
```

As result you have only one test which is data driven.

Comment: what if i need to customize the assert result based on different permission. anyway I can specified the params to pass for each testcase? like userA_permission, I need to verify a,b, c. userB_permission, I need to verify d,e ,f.

Comment: In this case you can use a list instead of a dict as an expected result. Or any other complicated object, that fits to your needs.

Comment: If it does not work for you, then you may have separate test for each permission but invoke set permission to userA as a first step inside your test (without using fixtures): `

        def set_permission_to_userA(permission):
        login_with_admin()
        set_permission(permission)

    def test_premission_one():
        set_permission_to_userA(permission1)
        login_with_userA()
        verifications_here()

    def test_premission_two():
        set_permission_to_userA(permission2)
        login_with_userA()
        verifications_here()

    `

Comment: get you, thank you. I just have the separated testcase as approach